# se puede programar en c# para la web

Tags: javascript, c#, web

estoy aprendiendo javascript para tener una mejor pagina web, pero lo que e escuchado es que se puede programar en varios lenguajes de programacion enlazados con html.

yo aprendi c# hace tiempo y quiero programar desde el para no usar javascript, lo que me ocurre es que quiero mostrar un mensaje en la pagina desde c# y no puedo, osea no me sale nada, estoy usando el Console.WriteLine() y no ocurre nada, no se si estoy perdido y simplemente debo aprender javascript o solo no tengo el conocimiento en c#.

ayuda por favor

Comment: Existe un framework llamado .NET framework, si no estoy mal es perfecto para programar casi cualquier cosa en los lenguajes C#, VB y F# ademas es multiplataforma y creado por microsoft, quizá te interese https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet

Comment: Por cierto @AlejandroCardona ya que veo que eres nuevo en el sitio, te doy la bienvenida a stackoverflow en español y de paso porfavor te invito a que te pases por el [tour] del sitio y tambien que leas sobre [ask], tu pregunta no es apta para una respuesta y lo mas probable es que termine cerrada o con votos negativos, toma estas recomendaciones en cuenta (los links que puse), para poder que puedas hacer mejores preguntas en un futuro, saludos y espero te haya servido la información!

Comment: estas queriendo usar una sintaxis para Consola. Deberias realizar un proyecto web con asp net - asp net core. Pero necesitas c#, html, javascript, sql para realizar un proyecto web. Porque javascript te permitira hacer tareas que no necesiten del servidor o el codebehind del sitio para poder hacer ciertas logicas que tu creas necesarias. Y claro que te falta mas conocimiento de todos los lenguajes.

Comment: muchas gracias.